# Get upload file name into textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload

I am trying to get the filename of the uploaded file into a textbox via jquery. It should be easy enough if there is single file upload button.

But I have file input as an array and beside each file upload button there is a textbox.

I have created a fiddle which will demonstrate more clearly. The problem is I can't get the value/name of the selected file on change function.

```
$('.imgupload').on('change', function (e) {
    var filenames = [].slice.call(e.target.files).map(function (f) {
        alert(f.name);
        return f.name;
    });
    $('#filename').val(filenames);
});
```

JSFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Ldcp7hoc/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but there is no input with `id="filename"`, you do have `filename1`, `filename2` and `data-id` variables.  So just grab the `data-id` and give the corresponding input (first, second, etc.) the value equal to your `var filename` which you were getting correctly.

```
$('#ques_32\\[\\]').on('change', function (e) {
    var filename = [].slice.call(e.target.files).map(function (f) {
        return f.name;
    });
    $('#filename' + $(this).attr("data-id")).val(filename);
});
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldcp7hoc/5/)

By the way you had a typo in your fiddle, wrote `dataid` instead of `data-id`

Comment: Hey Dan...that's awesome. Brilliant!! Thanks a lot for saving my rest of the night :p